# Escape single quote in xslt concat function

Tags: xslt, xml, javascript

I want to output single quote around $ID variable in the below **xsl:value-of** xsl statment.

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat('process[@Ref=',$ID,']')"></xsl:value-of>
```

currently it prints

```
process@Ref=87799989
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Good Question (+1). See my answer for a complete solution. :)

Comment: Good Question (and answered thankfully!) ; this was driving me nuts !

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Use `&apos;`?

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat('process[@Ref=&apos;',$ID,'&apos;]')"></xsl:value-of>
```

Edit: See [Dimitre's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2888544/224671) for a better solution.

Comment: It's odd this worked; as &apos; should be decoded equivalent to a literal '.  Perhaps a buggy XSLT engine?

Comment: Yuo need to use both &apos; and the single quote together: ```&apos;'```

Comment: @Vadi - &apos; and the single quote doesn't seem to work for gmail filters but it worked without the single quote.

Comment: @Vadi - Thanks a lot for that suggestion. I went crazy trying to escape it.

Answer (score 52):

**In XPath 1.0**:

You can use the built-in entities `&apos;` and `&quot;`

**In XSLT 1.0**:

Alternatively, you can define your `$Q` and `$APOS` variables (put the content (the literal " or the literal ' character) in the body of the `xsl:variable`, not in the `select` attribute).

**In XPath 2.x** (this also means XSLT 2.x and XQuery 1.x)

Simply escape an apostrophe by entering two adjacent apostrophes, escape a quote by entering two adjacent quotes, **[as defined by the XPath 2.0 language](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/#id-literals)**

Comment: Could you please provide examples? (one example tells more than 1000 words and pushes your answer to the top). Thanks

Comment: @RichardGomes, See this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7617563/36305 ,or this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3453956/36305 , or this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8783655/36305

Answer (score 40):

To expand on Dimitre's answer, you can use this solution in XSLT:

```xml
<xsl:variable name="apos">'</xsl:variable>
<xsl:value-of select="concat('process[@Ref=',$apos,$ID,$apos,']')"></xsl:value-of>
```

Comment: The variable method works and looks the most readable (IMHO).

Comment: This is the second time that this solution has saved me wasting hours of trial and error and debugging time.

Comment: Seems to work in XSLT 1.0 and 2.0, which I liked because then I can put it into a common.xslt file.

Answer (score 5):

```
<xsl:value-of
select="concat('process[@Ref=&apos;',$ID,'&apos;]')"></xsl:value-of>
```

this doesn't work for me. My solution is:

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat(&quot;process[@Ref='&quot;,$oidConstant,&quot;'&quot;)"></xsl:value-of>
```

Comment: I was skeptical but this works - the plain text double quote contains the select statement and the encoded doubles are consumed by the parser - nice

Answer (score 0):

Easy Example would be

```
      <xsl:variable name="varTitle" select="title" />
<xsl:variable name="APOS">'</xsl:variable>
<xsl:value-of select="translate($varTitle, 'any text', $APOS)"/>
```

This will replace "any text" with ' in my title.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `concat()`, you can do the string concatenation inside a variable assignment. That allows to write a simple, unescaped `'` to mean `'`:

```
<xsl:variable name="process-selector">process[@Ref='<xsl:value-of select="$ID"/>']</xsl:variable>
<xsl:value-of select="$process-selector" />
```

With the [recommended way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3637475) to allow linebreaks without accidentally adding whitespace to the output, this becomes quite lengthy (but that's XSL, right?):

```
<xsl:variable name="process-selector">
    <xsl:text>process[@Ref='</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="$ID"/>
    <xsl:text>']</xsl:text>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:value-of select="$process-selector" />
```

---

Full XSL file for this solution to test, for example with an online XSL-T service like [xsltransform.net](http://xsltransform.net/):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="html"/>

    <xsl:template match="/" name="strip-space" >
        <xsl:variable name="ID" select="123"/>
        <xsl:variable name="process-selector">
            <xsl:text>process[@Ref='</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="$ID"/>
            <xsl:text>']</xsl:text>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:value-of select="$process-selector" />
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```