# concat, quotation mark and apostrophe combination problems

Tags: xslt, concatenation

I tried different ways and also looked around but can't get this running.
I need to concat the following:

```
"concat( 
    'this is; \"a sample',
    //XML_NODE,
    '\"; \"using an apostrophe',
    '&#39;',
    'in text\"'
)"
```

one line version:

```
"concat( 'this is; \"a sample', //XML_NODE, '\"; \"using an apostrophe', '&#39;', 'in text\"' )"
```

The output should be:

```
this is "a sample XML_NODE_VALUE"; "using an apostrophe ' in text"
```

The problem is the ' in the text. concat use it to end a string and expect an following ; or the end of concat. Escaping or HTML entities all seems to not work.

Any help is really appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: yeah and also &#39; and plain ' and \' and also without a new string

Comment: @Talisin: You may be interested in a solution that doesn't use any variable at all.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In XML/XSLT you do not escape characters with a backslash.

- In XML you can use entity references.
- In XSLT you can use entity references and variables.

The problem with the apostrophe inside of your concat strings is that the XML parser loading the XSLT will expand it before the concat gets evaluated by the XSLT engine; so you can't use an entity reference for the apostrophe character unless it is wrapped in double quotes (or entity references for double quotes, as Dimitre Novatchev's answer demonstrates).

- Use the entity reference `&quot;` for the double quote `"`.
- Create a variable for the apostrophe character and reference the variable as one of the components of the concat()

Applied in the context of an XSLT:

```
<xsl:variable name="apostrophe">'</xsl:variable>

<xsl:value-of select="concat( 
            'this is; &quot;a sample',
            //XML_NODE,
            '&quot;; &quot;using an apostrophe ',
            $apostrophe,
            ' in text&quot;'
            )" />
```

If you need a 100% XPath solution that avoids the use of XSLT variables, then Dimitre's answer would be best.

If you are concerned with how easy it is to read, understand, and maintain, then Michael Kay's suggestion to use XSLT variables for the quote and apostrophe might be best.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry for the backslash in the example, they are part of my PHP compiler and I forgot to delete them. Your example works great. Please node: <xsl:variable name="apostrophe" select=" ' "> won't work. Explanation and working solution +1! Thanks again.

Comment: @Mads Hansen: You may be interested in a solution that doesn't use any variable at all.

Comment: @Mads Hansen: Please, correct the false statement in this answer "*so you can't use an entity reference for the apostrophe character.*". The wanted string *can* be produced with a single call to `concat()` that doesn't involve any variable references.

Answer (score 6):

**No variable is necessary**:

Here is an example how to produce the wanted output in two ways:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:text>this is "a sample XML_NODE_VALUE"; "using an apostrophe ' in text"</xsl:text>
  =============
  <xsl:value-of select=
   "concat('this is ',
           '&quot;a sample XML_NODE_VALUE&quot;; &quot;',
           &quot;using an apostrophe &apos; in text&quot;,
           '&quot;'
          )
   "/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on any XML document (not used), the wanted output is produced**:

```
this is "a sample XML_NODE_VALUE"; "using an apostrophe ' in text"
=============
this is "a sample XML_NODE_VALUE"; "using an apostrophe ' in text"
```

Comment: thanks, I tried it with &apos; but it dosen't worked on my environment but it works on http://xslttest.appspot.com/ , so I guess there is something wrong with my environment than.

Comment: @Talisin: I work with a dosen of different XSLT 1.0 and XSLT 2.0 processors -- all of them produce the same result. You may be using an incompliant XSLT processor.

Comment: Yeah I don't think that the problem is the processor. I am pretty sure it is my PHP environment which creates the XSL and can't handle this case. Need to run some unit test's to see what's going on. Thanks for your help. Really appreciated it.

Comment: @Talisin: Actually, it isn't even the XSLT processor -- it is the parser that the XSLT processor uses.

Answer (score 4):

I find the easiest solution is to declare variables:

```
<xsl:variable name="apos">'</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="quot">"</xsl:variable>
<xsl:value-of select="concat('This is ', $quot, "a sample using ", $apos)"/>
```