# How to select element that contains single quotes using XPath?

Tags: html, xpath, escaping

I would like to select this element using `XPath`:

```
<a href="#" onClick="onViewDocument('2016', '1');">2016</a>
```

So far I have this:

```
//a[@onClick='onViewDocument('2016', '1');']
```

Do I need to escape the single quotes around the `2016` and `1`?

Comment: There are solutions for most languages... I.e. XSLT http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8783086/concat-quotation-mark-and-apostrophe-combination-problems, c# http://stackoverflow.com/questions/642125/encoding-xpath-expressions-with-both-single-and-double-quotes... Unfortunately HTML alone does not define a programming  language (and it dos not use XPath anywhere to my knowledge)... For more answers - https://www.bing.com/search?q=xpath%20quotes%20concat

Comment: @CJ7:  You've gotten quality answers to [nearly 500 questions](http://stackoverflow.com/users/327528/cj7?tab=questions&sort=newest), yet your accept ratio is absolutely abysmal, you've only every upvoted 23 times in 6 years, and you've answered less than a tenth as often as you've asked questions.   ***Why not give back a bit in some way or other?***

Answer (score 2):

Simplest usually is to use the alternative of `'` or `"`, depending upon what was already used surrounding the string literal.

If that's not feasible, an alternative is to use `&apos;` for `'` (*single quote*):

```
//a[@onClick='onViewDocument(&apos;2016&apos;, &apos;1&apos;);']
```

Note that you can use `&quot;` for `"` (*double quote*).

**Reference**: **[XML Path Language (XPath) Version 1.0](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#section-Introduction)**:

> XPath expressions often occur in XML attributes. The grammar specified
>   in this section applies to the attribute value after XML 1.0
>   normalization. So, for example, if the grammar uses the character `<`,
>   this must not appear in the XML source as `<` but must be quoted
>   according to XML 1.0 rules by, for example, entering it as `&lt;`.
>   Within expressions, literal strings are delimited by single or double
>   quotation marks, which are also used to delimit XML attributes. To
>   avoid a quotation mark in an expression being interpreted by the XML
>   processor as terminating the attribute value the quotation mark can be
>   entered as a character reference (`&quot;` or `&apos;`). Alternatively,
>   the expression can use single quotation marks if the XML attribute is
>   delimited with double quotation marks or vice-versa.

Answer (score 0):

This is for all elements that contain `'` in `onclick`:

```
//a[contains(@onclick, "'")]
```

This is for the specific element you're trying to match:

```
//a[@onClick="onViewDocument('2016', '1')"]
```