# Removing Special Characters XSLT

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I keep receiving this error message

> Required attribute 'select' is missing.

I already used this code before and it was working fine, but it seems that it is not applicable to

```
<xsl:output method="text" />
```

Hope you can help me.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday.report/Sample_Outbound">

    <xsl:output method="text" />
            <xsl:variable name="linefeed" select="'&#xA;'"></xsl:variable>
            <xsl:variable name="StreetAddress1">Street Address 1</xsl:variable>

    <xsl:template match="wd:Report_Data">
        <File>
            <!-- Header -->
            <Header>
                <StreetAddress1>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$StreetAddress1" />
                </StreetAddress1>
                <xsl:value-of select="$linefeed" />
            </Header>

            <xsl:for-each select="wd:Report_Entry">
                <Record>
                    <Work_Street_Address_1>
                        <xsl:call-template name="Remove-Special-Characters-Commas">
                        <xsl:with-param name="normalize-string"
                             select="wd:Work_Street_Address_1"  />
                        </xsl:call-template>
                    </Work_Street_Address_1>

                    <xsl:value-of select="$linefeed" />
                </Record>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </File>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="Remove-Special-Characters-Commas">
        <xsl:param name="normalize-string" />
        <xsl:variable name="AllowedSymbols"
            select="'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789-.,#():@/;\'&apos;_&amp;'" />
        <xsl:variable name="stringValuePreformatted"
            select="translate($normalize-string,'àâäèéêëîïôœùûüÿÀÁÄÈÉÊËÎÏÔŒÙÛÜŸçÇáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚäöüÄÖÜßàèéìòóùÀÈÉÌÒÓÙáéíóúüÁÉÍÓÚÜñÑ¿¡','aaaeeeeiioeuuuYAAAEEEEIIOEUUUYCCaeiouAEIOUaouAOUBaeeioouAEEIOOUaeiouuAEIOUUnN?1')" />
        <xsl:value-of
            select="normalize-space(translate($stringValuePreformatted, translate($stringValuePreformatted, $AllowedSymbols,''),''))" />
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The line error is

```
line 39: Error parsing XPath expression ''abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789-.,#():@/;\''_&''.
line 39: Required attribute 'select' is missing.

enter code here
```

Thanks

Comment: In what line do you receive that error message? I ask this question, because you do not provide a [mcve].

Comment: Here is the a sample xslt code.

Comment: try removing the `\'` before the `&apos;`

Comment: It might be helpful if you'd post the XML sample as well. Just  to complete the [mcve].

Comment: thank you all for the replies I already removed code '&apos;_&amp; and the code didn't error out. @zx485 - i'll take note of that to complete all and sorry to :).

Comment: You marked you question as *xslt-1.0*, but the included XSLT fragment starts from *stylesheet version="2.0"*. Please correct this ambiguity.

Answer (score -1):

Replace your line

```
<xsl:variable name="AllowedSymbols" select="'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789-.,#():@/;\'&apos;_&amp;'" />
```

by

```
<xsl:variable name="apos">'</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="AllowedSymbols" select="concat('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789-.,#():@/;_\&amp;',$apos)" />
```

and everything should work as expected.
In this approach I used [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6364614/1305969) for handling the `'` situation by using a variable.

Comment: I'm afraid that *&quot;* stands for **double** quote.

Comment: The question is about keeping the `'` character. Changing the problem to  keeping a different character `"` is not a valid answer.

Comment: @michael.hor257k: I changed my answer accordingly.

Comment: @Valdi_Bo: I changed my answer accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

The source of your problem is `&apos;`. Replace it with 2 apostrophes.

Comment: To proof what I wrote, check the following saved XSLT: http://xsltransform.net/gWEamMh

Comment: This question is tagged XSLT 1.0. Escaping single/double quotes by doubling them only works in XPath/XSLT 2.0.

Comment: But look at the XSLT included in the question. It starts with **version="2.0"**.

Answer (score -1):

The simplest way to solve the problem is to change the definition of the variable from:

```
<xsl:variable name="AllowedSymbols"
       select="'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789-.,#():@/;\'&apos;_&amp;'" />
```

to:

```
<xsl:variable name="AllowedSymbols">abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789-.,#():@;&apos;_&amp;</xsl:variable>
```

---

Alternatively, you could switch the single and double quotes around like this:

```
<xsl:variable name="AllowedSymbols"
       select='"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789-.,#():@;&apos;_&amp;"'/>
```

but then you won't be able to add a double quote to the list.